# Prime Faces InputText inside an ordered list

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a requirement in primefaces to have an inputText inside an orderlist and on changing the inputText want to reflect it in the object model. But i suppose there is a bug or some kind of problem as whenever I submit the form there is a null pointer error. It says that the object is unreachable. The weird part is that it does show the correct data (ie. gets the data) but is unable to set it.

```
<p:orderList value="#{artifactController.uploadedFiles}"
                    var="uploadedFile" itemValue="#{uploadedFile}"
                    controlsLocation="left" id="artifactList"
                    converter="customUploadedFileConverter" 
                    selection="#{artifactController.selectedUploadedFile}"
                    selectionMode="single">
                    <p:column style="width:25%">
                        <p:graphicImage
                            value="/faces/pages/image#{uploadedFile.imagePath}?mimeType=#{uploadedFile.mimeType}"
                            width="100" height="50">
                        </p:graphicImage>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width:75%;">
                        <p:inputText value = #{uploadedFile.fileName} ></p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:orderList>
```

The Controller has all the setters and getters in place.
The input text shows the data while retrieving but fails to update the value in the controller. Isn't it supposed to work like that (similar to dataTable). It gives uploadedFile is unreachable error.

Comment: Please provide a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: Sorry guys..I have edited the question with the code..Thanx for ur response